# .dygraph-legend Class in CSS Won't Change My Dygraph Legend

Tags: css, dygraphs

For the dygraph that I've made in my app, the legend and title default to show in the top left of the graph and they overlap with the y-axis, making them hard to read. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mccosk/6nk5vw2g/

Relevant Snippet  (CSS):

```
.dygraph-legend {
    left: 400px !important;
}
.dygraph-title {
    color: red;
}
```

The fiddle looks just how I want it to (with the title/legend centered) but here is how it comes out when I run my app:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCGqK.png)

I'm confused because I can change the color of the title through css, but my code under the class ".dygraph-legend" seem to have no effect. I have both dygraph.js and dygraph.css downloaded I import them in my html file.

Any advice on how to fix this would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can not test your app, I only can suggest a little fix like next one. Set the margin-left as a number of pixels or as a percentage. Hope it works for you.

```
.dygraph-label.dygraph-title {
  margin-left: 10% !important;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: My savior! Thank you so much.